Advise pls on how to raise Trilingual kid
I’m expecting my first baby in January 2025.
I’m Thai and my husband is German. We both work and live in the UK. We communicate to each other in English.
I have no clue about the German language and my husband also can’t understand any Thai.
I have see a lot of people say one parent one language. But when we speak to each other in English is this going to confuse the baby? Or when we go outside meet our friends, when we have to communicate to each other in English as well?
I know that my baby will learn English eventually when she goes to the nursery or primary school. Is this going to delay her development?
Or any advise on this please.

We have tons of questions/answers on trilingual households/kids. A look around might help. If you plan to stay in an English-speaking country, (imo) almost no matter how hard you try, your child will soon speak only English at home. Frustrating for parents, but pretty natural for the child.

See https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/39901/36241 and also https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/39653/36241
